# How many ships would it take to destroy a Sith or Jedi piloted ship?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-vader

I remember reading in Shadows of the Empire how Vader loved to "occasionally get into the TIE Fighter and flex his force muscles" (Star Wars 4).

With the new Rogue One movie coming up, it seems they may have a point where we get to see this again-remember from Star Wars 4 and 6 the Rebels said many died bringing them information on the Death Star, and there aren't any Jedi Masters to really challenge Vader.

So I figured we might get a nice space-fighter climatic battle (crossing fingers). So how many ships would it take to overwhelm him?

Comment: Are you asking about Vader specifically?

Comment: Somewhere between 'one' and 'all of them', depending on any number of factors.

Comment: Let's find out... one, twohoo, three *crunch*. Three

Comment: The Force could help Jedi and Sith to take some advantages, but it doesn't make them good pilots. Skywalkers are - Vader is naturally an amazing pilot and he is strong in the Force.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Plo Koon's clone trooper buddy was [able to kill him singlehandedly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttU-7pOUpDI). Han of course also took out Vader [more or less by himself](https://youtu.be/2WBG2rJZGW8?t=13m7s). So the lame answer appears to be: one, if you have the element of surprise.

On the other hand, there's a scene in the radio play of A New Hope in which the rebels put Luke through a combat simulation to see if he's up to scratch before the Battle of Yavin. It's stated that they pit Luke against the equivalent of *the entire Imperial fleet*, and [he only manages to die twice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68750/30859). So for Jedi like Luke and Anakin who are stated to be exceptional pilots even before their training, the answer is probably lots and lots and LOTS of ships.

But you have to keep in mind that there are a lot of factors at play. What if they have a crappy ship, with bad turning or speed? What if their opponents have better shielding and better targeting computers? In the end, so much of a space battle has to due with technological factors outside of a Jedi's control.

Comment: How ordinary shmucks managed to get the drop on two trained Force users is a question for another day.

Comment: There is also the possibility that the Force user's precognitive ability would prompt him to avoid the confrontation altogether.