# Who are all these rebel pilots?

Tags: star-wars

While rewatching *A New Hope*, I noticed in the final ceremony that there were a sizable section that were pilots, as indicated by their orange flight jumpsuits (middle section of ceremony congregation)

[image: ceremony]

My understanding was that all pilots on Yavin 4 took part in the attack on the Death Star, and only a handful came back. **So who are all these rebels in pilot jumpsuits?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is addressed in the (canon) short story [Duty Roster](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duty_Roster). In short, due to equipment shortages there are significantly more trained Rebel pilots than there are ships for them to fly.

> “Like that, huh? Can’t say I blame you. Let’s get to it. **You all know
>   we have more pilots than birds.** Given our losses at Scarif, we’re
>   trying to figure out if we can even put Green and Blue squadrons
>   together. I’d fly with anyone in this room—and you all deserve a place
>   on this hop. But unfortunately that can’t happen.”

Add to that pilots for various spaceships that weren't needed for the mission and you've got a contingent of pilots that weren't involved in the Battle of Yavin.

Comment: Which then opens bigger can of worms, why did they let some kid from Tatooine who never saw X-wing before in his life, pilot one in most crucial and desperate battle for Rebellion :D

Comment: @rs.29 - Worthy of its own question

Comment: Actually, there was such question, but I'm not sure accepted answer is still relevant today : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68745/why-did-the-rebels-allow-luke-to-fly-an-x-wing-against-the-death-star

Comment: @rs.29 open a bounty (as reward for updating answer) and possibly submit your own answer?

Comment: @Boolean I'm not sure there is in-universe answer, and going into details would only make plot hole bigger. When I watched the movie first time it seemed natural to have main character in final battle. Only latter it dawned to me that any semi-serious military organization would not risk giving fighter plane to a kid who never flew one, except if they are really desperate and have no other choice (for example like Japan or Germany 1944/45)

Comment: @rs.29 - I've added an answer to that question. He was personally recommended by two of the Rebellion's leaders and had simulator scores higher than any other pilot in the fleet.

Comment: @rs.29 - because the force was with him...